# SQL: Trouble returning distinct like values from a subquery and join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, distinct

**query:**

```
select DOG_CD,ANIMAL_CD 
from FKAGM
where FKAG = 12024
```

**Displays 3 rows**

`DOG_CD - ANIMAL_CD` are column names and below each column is 3 numerical values yielded from the above query & I have no clue how to draw a table on here to depict that. =(

There is a table called Dog_Animal that has a column called "Name" (Dog_Animal.Name) that I want to join with this above query. I want to join on ANIMAL_CD as FKAGM table and the DOG_ANIMAL table have the ANIMAL_CD column in common. I'd like to display "Name" right next to the ANIMAL_CD column. The issue is when I join the tables it displays like every instance of DOG_CD and ANIMAL_CD within the Dog_Animal table (Which is thousands) something similar to the below illustration. since the Dog_Animal table has thousands of DOG_CD and ANIMAL_CODE fields populated. I just want it to be limited to the three rows that are returned by the above query (Limit or distinct or something) and input the Dog_Animal.Name next to Animal_CD. I've been working on this for an hour and I know it must be so simple, but I can't seem to get it to work. I am not sure if a subquery is needed or exists, or case, or what. If you can figure this out I would be so thankful!

`DOG_CD - ANIMAL_CD - Dog_Animal.Name` with the same 3 rows of data just now a name included

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
f.DOG_CD,f.ANIMAL_CD,d.name
from FKAGM f
inner join dog_animal d
on d.animal_cd = f.animal_cd
where f.FKAG = 12024;
```

`inner join` would work for you. If you only need to limit it to 3 results, add `limit 3 order by f.dog_cd` at the end of your query.

Comment: I don't think you need limit 3. Because as OP say the original query already return 3. Inner join should be enough.

Comment: This query returned 948 rows. :( I know this has to be close. I just don't know why it is returning so many values.

Comment: are they duplicates? if so, use `distinct`

Comment: They aren't duplicates. It confuses me too. With f.fkag =12024 shouldn't it be reduced to only the values at that value? I just don't know where it is getting all of these extra rows. selecting * from the FKAGM table it has 5.5k rows on its own and dog_animal has 3.1k so I'm just kinda lost where this 948 is coming from. Would some sort of subquery maybe work? or CASE I have no real experience using CASE.

Comment: it would be better if you post your table structures in the question.